# Why is any condition in COUNT() function evaluated as true?

Tags: sql, count, window-functions

In a column for gender containing only the values 'M' and 'F', why does a sql COUNT() function evaluate COUNT(gender = 'L') or COUNT(gender = 0) same as COUNT(*).

Comment: What RDBMS are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL `COUNT()` function doesn't accept a filtering expression as a parameter, in general. The parameter should be the columns that you are counting. So, likely what you want is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM {table}
WHERE gender = 'L'
```